# Offset PHP Query by number?

Tags: php, wordpress, offset

I'm using WordPress and using two queries that are the same.

Basically you've got "Featured Content" that is displaying the 6 latest posts. Under that is a section that needs to display 2 more latest posts, but after the 6 that are in featured. Is there some kind of PHP query that can find the latest posts and offset by an amount (example 6) to display posts after the featured 6?

Thanks!

Comment: Im guessing you havent tried searching anything. http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is an offset parameter, example:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts#Posts_list_with_offset

Comment: Thanks a lot! Worked perfectly.